# Is it possible to get an HTML element's attribute by PHP

Tags: php

I know that by using jQuery, I can use `$('span').attr('title')` to get the value of attribute's title, but how can I use PHP to do that?

BEFORE

`<span title="2012-11-22 15:35">6 小時前</span>`

AFTER

`<span>22/11/2012 15:35</span>`

Comment: Do you have the `<span>` in a string _in PHP_ on the server, or are you hoping to do this in the client browser (you can't)?

Comment: Why do you need to do that with PHP? If want to do with PHP just send output as what you want `<span>22/11/2012 15:35</span>`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes, I have `<span>` in the string, and want to do that before rendering to browser.

Comment: @CharlesYeung: you could add your comment with your question for more details otherwise your question does not make sense

Comment: @Positive It is a dynamic string, so I can't direct output

Comment: @CharlesYeung: so what, you can still explain this in your question. you don't know but this help us to answer the question

Answer (score 1):

You can load this into a DOM Document, or use simplexml.

Example with DOM Document:

```
// Load your HTML as a string here, or you can open a file (see docs)
$myHtml = new \DOMDocument();
$myHtml->loadHTML($htmlString);

// Get all span tags
$spans = $myHtml->getElementsByTagName('span');

foreach ($spans as $span) {
    // get
    $span->getAttribute('title');

    // set  
    $span->setAttribute('title', 'new title');

    // append text node (like innerHTML)
    $span->appendChild($myHtml->createTextNode('something'));
}
```

To replace the text of the element you would need to create a TextNode and append to the span.

Answer (score 0):

HTML can be parsed using [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) with [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php). Xpath can be used to select any element in the html provided by an attribute.